# Reserved Memory Addresses?

Tags: memory, memory-management, reserved

Is there a list of reserved memory addresses out there - a list of addresses that the memory of a user-space program could never be allocated to?  I realize this is most likely per-OS or per-architecture, but I was hoping someone might know some of the more common OSes and Arches.  I could only dig one up for a few versions of windows:

> for windows NT,2k and XP that would be:
>
> 0x00000000 - 0x0000ffff -> lowest page is protected to simplify debugging
>
> 0x00001000 - 0x7ffeffff -> memory area for your application
>
> 0x7fff0000 - 0x7fffffff -> protected area to keep memory-functions from damaging the following part
>
> 0x80000000 - 0xffffffff -> memory where the system including drivers and so on is located

Anyone know about for Linux, or BSD (or anything else, for that matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is normally configured to own 0xC000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF by kernel. This can be changed (e.g. the infamous 4GB-4GB split that reserves none). glibc is usually loaded at 0xB000000.

Under Linux, 0x00000000 can be requested by a particular mmap() call unless blocked by a security sysctl (which turned out to be a bad idea to block).

Reguarding allocating NULL:

> NULL is only explicitly allocatable so I'd assume the program that did it was prepared for the consequence of doing so. At least `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` is required to GCC for the affected code to function. I'm told this is to emulate old BSD behavior that mapped the zero page there.

Comment: That confuses me a little - if NULL is allocatable, what does that do for all the programs that initialize to it?  Do you know of any good resources that talk about this issue?